# Is there anyway to identify which editor is currentEditor in SlickGrid?

Tags: slickgrid

I wanted to identify which Slick editor is being used in the current selected Column. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got.

We can use activeCell with columns to get the current select column. Then from the column.editor attribute, we cloud compare what is the editor currently select cell possess.

```
var column = columns[activeCell];
    if(column.editor && column.editor === Slick.Editors.Text)
    {
        // Code with identification.
    }
```